# How can I register a Wcf Service contract without knowing the implementation

Tags: wcf, castle-windsor

Without Castle Windsor I would write:

```
var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<ICredentialService>("Default"); 
ICredentialService credentialService = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
```

How can I register a Wcf Service contract with the Castle Windsor API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the [Castle Windsor WCF integration facility](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Castle.WcfIntegrationFacility/) Nuget package to your project

Add the `WcfFacility` to your container:

```
container.AddFacility<WcfFacility>();
```

Then, tell the container to provide a WCF client when you have a dependency on your service interface:

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<ICredentialService>()
        .AsWcfClient(WcfEndpoint.FromEndpoint("EndpointName")));
```

It will then use the named endpoint in your .config to retrieve the settings for the endpoint.

Whenever a class resolved from the container has a constructor dependency on `ICredentialService` the container will inject a WCF client.